# How to CONTAIN a PHP variable echoed content in a DIV

Tags: php, css

Hello My question is not how to echo a php variable into a DIV.    My question is how to contain it.  When I enter text into the DIV it expands and contains text, but the echoed php Variable content from the variable  crosses the boundery Vertically at the bottom only.  Overflow:hidden works but then it does not expand with the content.

```
** CSS ** 
.bottom-menu-body{
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;


** DIV ** 
 <div class="card">
 <div class="bottom-menu-body">

 <?php echo $bidcard; ?> <!-- Bid Card Content from Require: db_ac_bids.php-->
  
 <?php echo $nobids_message; ?> <!-- Bid Card Content from Require: db_ac_bids.php
 CSS control via acceptbid css card-->
  

</div><!--  Bottom Menu body End -->
</div><!-- Card end -->
```

Comment: All else being equal, that won't happen. Provide a [mcve]. The PHP is irrelevant, only the generated HTML. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Thanks I wil check it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not able to understand the question properly but I guess below css might help you :

```
div {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

"text-overflow: ellipsis" this will add "..." ellipsis.

Comment: The question says that they want the element to "expand with the content"

Comment: Thanks For explaining the question and Somesh thanks for the CSS options I will try it

Comment: Look like the  contain issue only happens when in mobile phone size.   when  Css column collapse happens so I need to investigate this further.  the issue is in my Sql Statement results layout.   overflow: hidden will  help in the end. Thanks